# Convert .ppt to Word - with proper headings, font-sizes and page-sizes

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, conversion, microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

How do I convert .ppt to .docx [or .odt, or something!] in such a way page sizes are scaled down and text is in "normal" font-sizes?

Comment: If it's just for sharing, maybe you can use a pdf-printer. You can't edit those, though.

Comment: Yeah, but that won't give it to me in an easy to read-multiple format.

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Downsized text, headers, and pushing as much as possible onto each A4 page.

Comment: If you use a pdf printer, you can actually make powerpoint do the downsizing. Just check out the print dialog.